# Django and Heroku - How do I get an absolute path to my static files in production?

Tags: django, heroku

In my settings.py file:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

How can I get an absolute **local** path to the static root from one of my view methods? (Not the template.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`request.build_absolute_uri()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.build_absolute_uri) built-in method. Pass it the relative URL (`/static/`) and it will return the absolute one.

#### UPDATE

To open/read the file in your view:

```
cool = open(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'cool_styles.css', 'rb').read()
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant a local path that I can use to open and read a file. I clarified my question.